# chrome floating images not displaying properly

Tags: image, internet-explorer, google-chrome, html

I'm trying to create a "News" control (facebook style) for my band's website, but I have a problem on google chrome.

this is the control (i'm going to write that in a custom webcontrol class to programmatically add controls with c# asp.net)

```
<div runat="server" id="Div1" style="width:900px; margin-bottom:10px;height:auto">
<img runat="server" id="Img1" src="" alt="" style="width:150px;height:250px;float:left"/>
<h1 runat="server" id="H1" style="color:Silver;margin-bottom:0px">Title</h1>
<div runat="server" id="Div2" style="color:Silver" align="right">date</div>
<div runat="server" id="Div3" style="color:Silver;word-wrap:break-word;float:right;width:740px">body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body 
body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body 
body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body 
body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body body 
</div>
</div>
```

my problem is: i got what i want using IE , but if i try to open in google chrome i got these images (adding more than one news) floating one next to the other, moving all the text badly (sorry, i can't post images) what can i do?

thank you, and sorry for my english :)

Comment: Have you heard of external stylesheets?

Comment: ..... i was just trying to understand how to make it work... that's not what i'm going to add to my page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the outside div does not take up all of its content. To do that, you can either use `clear:both` or `float:left` or `overflow:hidden` to the outside div element.